# Could a half-veela inherit metamorphmagus traits from their wizard parent?

Tags: harry-potter

I'm making a character, and I want them to be half Veela. But I also want them to be a metamorphmagus. I've looked at Half-Breed wiki pages, Half-Veela wiki pages, Metamorphmagus wiki pages, and Blood Status wiki pages, but none of them have mentioned inheriting metamorphmagus traits if you are not full-wizard.

Comment: Teddy was a half-werewolf. Does that count?

Comment: Is he half werewolf? I guess I missed that. I suppose it could work, if Teddy had shown some sort of "Werewolf Trait" since he was born, along side metamorphmagus traits as well. If the inheritance rules are similar then it should count.

Comment: What is exact question you have? Dominate and recessive traits in half-breed wizards?

Comment: Is there a way I can improve [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/148453/55866)?

Answer (score 2):

### Probably

While we don't know about Veela (seeing as there is no overlap between the canon examples of veela and metamorphmagi), we could try looking at werewolves.

Teddy Lupin is a half-werewolf and also a metamorphmagus.

> [image]
>   No doubt Potter will be distressed to know that his sixteen-year-old godson Teddy Lupin – **a lanky half-werewolf with bright blue hair** – has been behaving in a way unbefitting of wizarding royalty since arriving on the VIP campsite.
>   <sub><sub>Daily Prophet - Quidditch World Cup 2014 - "Dumbledore’s Army Reunites At Quidditch World Cup Final"</sub></sub>

> “ ’Oo does ’e look like?” Fleur inquired.
>
> “I think he looks like Dora, but she thinks he is like me. Not
>   much hair. It looked black when he was born, but I swear it’s turned
>   ginger in the hour since. Probably be blond by the time I get back.
>   Andromeda says Tonks’s hair started changing color the day that she
>   was born.”
>   <sub><sub>(*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - Chapter 25 ([text legally available online](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/some-very-welcome-news))</sub></sub>

So if we regard a half-Werewolves and and a half-Veela as the same type of magical status, then we see that they can inherit metamorphmagus traits.

Other than that, I don't think there's much to go on. But if you're trying to stay as canonically accurate as possible, I would avoid the wiki pages.